# Join two CSV files based on matching column data

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, csv, join

I would like to join data from two CSV files based on matching column information. The data to match is from File1.csv column 5, and File2 column 1, and i want to append the information from File2 column 2 upon match, and if no match leave empty double quotes.

**File1.csv**

```
"Z","P","W","K","1","1.18.24.59"
"S","K","D","X","9","1.14.19.238"
"R","M","P","Y","8","1.15.11.21"
"B","D","0","U","5","1.9.20.159"
"R","E","W","Q","6","135.0.0.1"
"K","D","K","R","9","1.9.74.13"
```

**File2.csv**

```
"65.9.7.19","374 22 53"
"1.9.74.13","123 256 51"
"1.18.24.59","23 25 41"
"1.15.11.21","98 77 8291"
"1.14.19.238","8827 145 8291"
"1.9.20.159","283 1 5734"
```

Desired Output

```
"Z","P","W","K","1","1.18.24.59","23 25 41"
"S","K","D","X","9","1.14.19.238","8827 145 8291"
"R","M","P","Y","8","1.15.11.21","98 77 8291"
"B","D","0","U","5","1.9.20.159","283 1 5734"
"R","E","W","Q","6","135.0.0.1",""
"K","D","K","R","9","1.9.74.13","123 256 51"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one solution, using `awk`.  Tested on GNU awk 4.1.3.

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2}NR!=FNR{print $0","(a[$6]?a[$6]:"\"\"")}' file2.csv file1.csv
"Z","P","W","K","1","1.18.24.59","23 25 41"
"S","K","D","X","9","1.14.19.238","8827 145 8291"
"R","M","P","Y","8","1.15.11.21","98 77 8291"
"B","D","0","U","5","1.9.20.159","283 1 5734"
"R","E","W","Q","6","135.0.0.1",""
"K","D","K","R","9","1.9.74.13","123 256 51"
$
```

- The `NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2` matches the lines in file2, and adds them into an array, keyed on field #1.
- The `NR!=FNR` then matches the lines in file1.
- `print $0","` prints the whole line from file1 followed by a comma.
- `(a[$6]?a[$6]:"\"\"")` prints the corresponding contents of the array built earlier, but just `""` if no entry found.

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be harder than I expected, but with the tools from the python-based `csvkit` version 1.0.2:

```
$ csvjoin -HI -c 6,1 --left File1.csv File2.csv 2>/dev/null | csvformat -K1 -U1
"Z","P","W","K","1","1.18.24.59","23 25 41"
"S","K","D","X","9","1.14.19.238","8827 145 8291"
"R","M","P","Y","8","1.15.11.21","98 77 8291"
"B","D","0","U","5","1.9.20.159","283 1 5734"
"R","E","W","Q","6","135.0.0.1",""
"K","D","K","R","9","1.9.74.13","123 256 51"
```

(The `-I` seems to be necessary to prevent `csvjoin` from guessing that the dot-separated fields are datetimes, at least in my locale.)

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in `cat file2.csv | awk -F "," '{print $1}'| sed 's/"//g'`; do j=`sed -n '/'$i'/p' file2.csv| awk -F "," '{print $2}'| sed 's/"//g'`;awk -v i="$i" -v j="$j" -F "," '$NF==i{$7=j;print $0}' file1.csv; done| sed 's/ /","/g'| sed 's/^/"/g'| sed 's/$/"/g'
```

output

```
"Z","P","W","K","1","1.18.24.59","23 25 41"
"S","K","D","X","9","1.14.19.238","8827 145 8291"
"R","M","P","Y","8","1.15.11.21","98 77 8291"
"B","D","0","U","5","1.9.20.159","283 1 5734"
"R","E","W","Q","6","135.0.0.1",""
"K","D","K","R","9","1.9.74.13","123 256 51"
```